# Размер типа данных

Tags: c++, sizeof

В программу на вход поступает строка с названием типа данных и требуется вывести размер этого типа данных

```
void main() 
{
  string str;

  getline(cin, str);

  cout << sizeof(str) << endl; // Как??
}
```

Comment: Восхитился. Но, откровенно говоря, если не подготовить таблицу заранее - то что-то не вижу способа...

Comment: @Harry Лежащий рядом компилятор и заготовленный шаблон `cout << sizeof(%type%)` плюс перенаправление вывода

Comment: ну я бы switch/case использовал :D хотя есть в cli и попробовать рефлекисей. но это уже бредом попахивает

Comment: @pavel по строкам?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov технический вопрос. по хешу от строк)

Comment: Просто есть выход сделать switch конструкцию, но я бы хотел узнать, есть ли другой метод вывести размер типа данных, который назван в строке